# adjusting dimensions of alert in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am making a basic app which has got an alert which would show up at the time the app is started. This alert has got a WebView in it and it covers almost the whole screen. Following are the questions I have in mind.

1. Now is it possible to adjust the dimensions of this alert ?
2. The url in the WebView in alert is set to 'http://www.google.com' let's say if some users are using my app and now I want them(users) to see a different webpage in the alert so how do I change the url without having them(users) update the app, how can I do it ?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.two;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.android.two.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        WebView wv = new WebView(this);
        wv.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.com");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }
        });

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Notification");
        alert.setView(wv);
        alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set dimensions for this alert dialog, by using custom layout for the **Alert Dialog**.

Please elaborate your second point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Dialog Layout like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="GO"
            android:id="@+id/go"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/urlText"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/web">

    </WebView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

We will use WindowManager.LayoutParams to adjust the dimension or we can set the height and width for the linearLayout above.

The  Activity Code will be:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView wv;
    EditText url;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        url=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.urlText);
        wv=(WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.web);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        Button go=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.go);
        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wv.loadUrl("http://"+url.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

        dialog.show();
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it Helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why does the alert dialog box cover almost entire screen even if I change the 'layout_width' and 'layout_height' in the custom dialog xml file

Comment: Because XML set the views first and then   lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;  Set it's dimension dynamically. If you change the dimensions here as per your requirement. It will work.

Comment: How to set dimensions dynamically ?

Comment: use lp.height=1300;
        lp.width=1100; or any other dimension as you like it to be. Also, lp.Gravity can be set to place the dialog towards top, left, right or bottom.